# Northwind: Select EmployeeID where the employee's average amount of sales exceeds the average amount of orders

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select `EmployeeID,FirstName` where the average amount of sales of emplyee exceeds the average amount of orders. I calculate the average amount of orders and average amount of sales of each employee but I could not perform the comparision because of subquery returns more than one value.

Average amount of orders:

```
select SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) 
from [Order Details] od 
join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID join Employees e on e.EmployeeID= o.EmployeeID
```

and

this is the amount of average sales for each employee:

```
select e.FirstName, SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) as AmountOfAverageOfSales 
from [Order Details] od join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID join Employees e on e.EmployeeID= o.EmployeeID
group by e.FirstName
```

I want to reach the `EmployeeID,FirstName` where amount of average sales of an employee exceeds the average amount of orders but as I said before subquery (second query) returns more then one value so query is not working when I use `where`. How can I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry If I waste time of someone. I have just solved it by using having.

```
select e.FirstName 
from (Orders o inner join Employees e on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID inner join [Order Details] od on o.OrderID=od.OrderID) group by e.FirstName
having SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-od.Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) > (select SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-od.Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID)
from [Order Details] od join Orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're needing the AvgOrders per employee or AvgOrders throughout. If it's the former...

```
select e.*, AvgOrders.AverageOrders, AvgSales.AmountOfAverageOfSales
From Employees e
inner join (select e.EmployeeID, SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) as AverageOrders
            from [Order Details] od 
            join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
            join Employees e on e.EmployeeID= o.EmployeeID
            group by e.EmployeeID)) AvgOrders on (e.EmployeeId = AvgOrders.EmployeeId)
inner join (select e.EmployeeID, SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) as AmountOfAverageOfSales 
            from [Order Details] od
            join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
            join Employees e on e.EmployeeID= o.EmployeeID
            group by e.EmployeeID) AvgSales on (e.EmployeeId = AvgSales.EmployeeId)
WHERE AvgSales.AmountOfAverageOfSales > AvgOrders.AverageOrders
```

If it's the latter you could use...

```
select e.*, AvgOrders.AverageOrders, AvgSales.AmountOfAverageOfSales
From Employees e
inner join (select SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) as AverageOrders
            from [Order Details] od 
            join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID)) AvgOrders on (1=1)
inner join (select e.EmployeeID, SUM((od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity)*(1-Discount))/COUNT(distinct o.OrderID) as AmountOfAverageOfSales 
            from [Order Details] od
            join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
            join Employees e on e.EmployeeID= o.EmployeeID
            group by e.EmployeeID) AvgSales on (e.EmployeeId = AvgSales.EmployeeId)
WHERE AvgSales.AmountOfAverageOfSales > AvgOrders.AverageOrders
```